# CodeIgniter - hidden controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I'm building a CMS based on CodeIgniter. It stores "views" and its data in a database and gathers the proper one when needed.
As you might have guessed - I can't generate a physical controller and matching view for each pages.

I've figured that **routes** would come in quite handy, since I'd prefer not to have to use a controller that's visible in the URL. Poorly explained: **I'm looking for a way to reassign all requests that doesn't end up on a physically existing controller to a custom one - without it appearing in the URL.** This controller would, of course, handle 404-errors and such.

Bad: `.com/handler/actual-view/)` Good: `(.com/actual-view/)` (no actual-view controller exists, or it'd be shown instead)

I've added a `404_override` route which points to `handler/`. Now, I'm only looking for a way to find out the requested view (i.e in `.com/actual-view` actual-view is what I'm looking for).

I've tried

```
$route['404_override/(:any)'] = 'handler/$1';
```

and similar, which will remove the 404-override completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, after some guidance from CodeIgniters awesome forum and StackOverflow's lovely members, became to route all 404 errors to my custom controller where I ensure that it's a real 404 (no views OR controllers). Later in the controller, I gather the rest of the info I need from my database URI string:

```
//Route
$route['404_override'] = 'start/handler';

//Controller
function handler($path = false) {

   //Gather the URI from the URL-helper
   $uri_string = uri_string();

   //Ensure we only get the desired view and not its arguments
   if(stripos($uri_string, "/") !== false) {
      //Split and gather the first piece
      $pieces = explode("/", $uri_string);
      $desired_view = $pieces[0];
   } else {
      $desired_view = $uri_string;
   }

   //Check if there's any view under this alias
   if($this->site->is_custom_view($desired_view)) {

      //There is: ensure that the view has something to show
      if(!$this->site->view_has_data($desired_view)) {
         //No data to show, throw an error message
         show_custom_error('no_view_data');
      } else {
         //Found the views data: show it
      }

   } else {
      //No view to show, lets go with 404
      show_custom_404();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better of [extending the base Router or Controller.](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html)

By doing so you allow your application to be flexible and still conform to how CI works.

Comment: Hmm.. would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Thats what the link to the documentation was for. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I actually don't understand the general concept. How would extending help me? I can't see how if I, somehow, wouldn't be able to change the loading order is being defined (controller -> 404 to controller -> custom -> 404)... Might be thinking in wrong circles, though ;-).

Comment: By extending the router, you can tell you application to check with a controller (ie your `handler` controller) before ending with the show_404().

Answer (score 0):

you need to define all of your valid routes in your route.php config file, and then at the last line,

```
$routes["(:any)"] = "specific controller path";
```

if I should give an example:

```
$route['u/(:any)/account'] = "user_profile/account/$1";
$route['u/(:any)/settings'] = "user_profile/settings/$1";
$route['u/(:any)/messages'] = "user_profile/messages/$1";
$route['u/(:any)'] = "user_profile/index/$1";
```

as seen here, I'm diverting all the urls to user profile, after the first three one couldn't catch it.

Comment: How would this fix the request that actually ends up on an existing controller? Your suggestion will force ALL requests to be handled by a specific controller.

Comment: no, it'll route the urls to a specific controller if any previous routes can't catch. I'm using it myself in my applications.

Comment: This does what I'm looking for, but it's kind of clutty to be honest, I'd prefer to just use the 404_override or similar instead (see updated OP).. Thanks for your reply :)!

Comment: well you didn't want the url to change, so this method or .htaccess (if you can write inside .htaccess which urls really are existing) will help you.